# Building support for in-app purchases into react native code

Tags: javascript, ios, app-store, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an iOS app with react native and need to add an in-app purchase from the App Store. How can I link up my (JS) react code with existing libraries for handling such functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content

In short, you can create a (native iOS) class that implements the react-specific "bridge" protocol (`RCTBridgeModule`), add in a few lines of code to the methods, and it will essentially be callable from JS.